Cross-reference to addsec
How can I make a cross-reference to a section that is included in the table of contents using addsec? Here my example:
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\addsec{Title I}\label{addsec:title-1}
See, e.g. section~\ref{sec:title-2} on page~\pageref{sec:title-2}
%% --
\section{Title II}\label{sec:title-2}
See, e.g. section~\ref{addsec:title-1} on page~\pageref{sec:title-1}
\end{document}  

Sure: the first cross-reference works, but the second does not. Is it even possible for the second one to work? I only want the page number that contains addsec.

well the \pageref will work if you correct your typo and use \pageref{addsec:title-1} instead of \pageref{sec:title-1}. The \ref can't work as there is no number it can output.  If you use hyperref you could use \nameref{addsec:title-1}.

@Ulrike, it is working with \nameref. Should have looked into the manual before posting the question.
